# Using global C# variables in Typescript

Tags: c#, visual-studio, typescript, razor

When writing Javascript code within a Razor/cshtml file, one may write code as follows:

```
if (lSelectedID == "@(Globals.MyGlobalVariable)") {
...
}
```

where Globals.MyGlobalVariable is a C# variable.
If Globals.MyGlobalVariable==123, then the resulting Javascript on the client will be

```
if (lSelectedID == "123") {
...
}
```

The above is very handy.  But how to do the same in Typescript? I.e. how to insert a C# global variable (or result of C# function call or whatever) into typescript before the typescript file is transformed to Javascript?

Answer (score 0):

It's not best practice to include JavaScript and CSS directly into your CSTHML. Rather you should have them in their own file and reference them in your view.

If your JavaScript is going to need some value from C# then you should store it  by using data attribute in your HTML elements.

Example:

```
<span id="myGlobalVariable" data-value="123456">MyGlobalVariable</span>
```

Then in your TypeScript get data you have set in your View

```
let myGlobalVariable = document.getElementById("myGlobalVariable").dataset.value;
if (lSelectedID == myGlobalVariable) {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest thing to do here would be to replicate your global variables in Typescript on the client side. This is how I've done it for my last two projects.

So on the server side you would have:

```
// C#

public class Globals()
{
    public int GlobalNum {get;} = 0;
    public string GlobalString {get;} = "123";
}
```

And on the client side, in Typescript it would be:

```
// Typescript 

export enum Globals{
    GlobalNum = 0;
    GlobalString = "123";
}
```

Now you can forget about the difficulty of trying to connect Razor (which renders server-side) to your Typescript (which executes on the client side), while still having a clear and obvious set of globals to refer to.

You code can then become:

```
// Typescript

if (lSelectedID == Globals.GlobalString) {
   //...
}
```

The only thing you need to keep in mind is that your global variables exist in two places - once on the server side and once on the client side.

Typescript demands that you replicate a lot of your server-side classes on the client side anyway, for receiving fetch response data properly, for example, so the addition of a `Globals` class/enum should not be too much of a break from the norm.

Comment: Thanks for comments.  Duplicate globals will not be my favorite, I will unfortunately forget to update one of them sooner or later..

Using html variables avoids this problem, but I try not using more then necessary hidden html variables.

I think I will rather include an additional parameter to my Typescript function, and include this parameter in my widget event handlers calling Typescript functions.
Seems to be quite a bit unnecessary when being used to Razor, but fair enough...

Comment: It really would be nice if Microsoft could provide some sort of injection of C# controlled values into Typescript when being inside Visual Studio, as is possible in Razor.